# Simplest way to show notification

Tags: flutter, dart, android-notifications

Is there any simple way to show notification in Flutter? I have already tried using [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications):

```
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
NotificationAppLaunchDetails notificationAppLaunchDetails;

Future<void> _showNotification(String msg) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        '696969', 'FCPN', 'FCPN Example',
        importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'plain title', msg, platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
}
```

but I have got null pointer

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you have to configure your Xcode files.

Add the following lines to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the `AppDelegate.m/AppDelegate.swift` file of your iOS project

Look at the Readme for `flutter_local_notifications` on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) for more info.